# Rails: activeadmin, undefined method `per' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x4d15ee0>

Tags: activeadmin

I installed ActiveAdmin successfully:

My gemfile code:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
 gem 'rails', '3.2.10'

 # Bundle edge Rails instead:
 # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

 gem 'sqlite3'


 # Gems used only for assets and not required
 # in production environments by default.
 group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

   # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
   # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 end

 gem 'jquery-rails'

 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

 gem 'activeadmin'

  # gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
 gem "spud_photos"
 gem 'devise'

 gem 'cancan'
 gem 'rolify'
```

and i did this:

```
 bundle
 rails g active_admin:install
 rake db:migrate
 rails g active_admin:resource product
```

I linked some models to ActiveAdmin.

Error after clicking in the dashboard on the product link:

```
 undefined method `per' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x4d15ee0>
```

Comment: This helped me: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2012/11/kaminari-willpaginate-incompatibility.html

Answer (score 41):

Active Admin need [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) pagination
If you want to use will paginate, you can make alias for will paginate functions to match kaminari one:

```
# config/initializers/will_paginate.rb
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        alias_method :per, :per_page
        alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
      end
    end
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    alias_method :total_count, :count
  end
end
```

And this one worked for me.

Comment: great it worked for me thanks please approve this one

Answer (score 26):

This one helped me:

```
 if defined?(WillPaginate)
   ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
     module WillPaginate
       module ActiveRecord
         module RelationMethods
           def per(value = nil) per_page(value) end
           def total_count() count end
         end
       end
       module CollectionMethods
         alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Don't forge to mention to add this code to a file and stick it in the config/initializers folder. I would name the file will_paginate.rb but use anything you'd like that would remind you what it's for.

Comment: and don't forget to restart the server

Comment: This solution solve my problem, Thanks! work for 2018!
My `Gemfile` have `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.1'`,  
no `gem kaminari` (will_paginate conflict with kaminari)
But in `Gemfile.lock` I saw `administrate` is using `kaminari`.
Anyway, I put these code into `config/initializers/will_paginate.rb`, and it work.!

Answer (score 11):

You can create an Initializer for Kaminari, like this:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

In my experience, I had to restart the server to make it work. That's all.

Answer (score 5):

The above answers do not work anymore. An updated answer was given [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/174) by @zitoon:

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        def per(value = nil) per_page(value) end
        def total_count() count end
      end
    end
    module CollectionMethods
      alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
    end
  end
end
```

I tried it myself. Works.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Ruby 2.1.5p273 and Rails 4.1.8. I encountered the same problem.
**@mohamed-ibrahim**'s answer solved the error `underfined method 'per'`, but got another error

> Showing c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-06bf79c58216/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #2 raised: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Adding `alias_method :total_count, :count` fixed it.

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        alias_method :per, :per_page
        alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
        alias_method :total_count, :count
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using kaminari and will_paginate together, you will definitely face this error. In short, kaminari and will_paginate are incompatible to each other. If you are using rails_admin (which uses kaminari for pagination) and also using will_paginate, you will need to add the following code to one of the initializers under config directory or you can create a new file, let say with name'will_paginate' add the code, and place it into initializers directory.

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        def per(value = nil) per_page(value) end
        def total_count() count end
      end
    end
    module CollectionMethods
      alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This was the only answer that didn't give me a "method missing" error from WillPaginate.  Using Rails 5.2 ruby 2.5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and switched from WillPaginate to Kaminari for my app.

It is a simple change: paginate(page:1,per_page:10) becomes page(1).per(10)

I guess it depends how deeply willPaginate is enmeshed with your app.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

initializers/will_paginate.rb

```
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        alias_method :per, :per_page
        alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
        alias_method :total_count, :total_entries
      end
    end
  end
end
```