# Active_admin NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using active_admin to generate an admin page on my rails app. I have had it for like a week, but suddenly today when I click the link emoticon which is a resource for the admin, I get this error :

NoMethodError in Admin::EmoticonsController#index

undefined method `per' for #

here is my emoticon controller :

```
 def index
    @emoticons = Emoticon.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end
```

I don't know, if I accidentally deleted one of active_admin file. But I recheck with the Railscast folder. And I think everything is fine. Anyone has any idea where the error could come from?

Please let me know if you need any other files.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958438/rails-activeadmin-undefined-method-per-for-activerecordrelation0x4d15ee

Comment: oops sorry didn't find it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [this](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-work-with-will_paginate)? Assuming you are working with `will_paginate`.